# why doesn't work top link button in google chrome

Tags: html

I add my page top link button like this:

<a name="top"></a>
.
.
.

<a href="#top" title="Top"><img src="images/top.png" alt="Top" id="toplink"/></a>

This is work in firefox well, but doesn't work in google chrome. Why?

Comment: Hi.  I've just tried this in Firefox v3.5 and Google Chrome v2.0.172.33 and it works fine in both browsers.  Could you give a little more detail?

Comment: It works with Chrome 2.0.172.33

Comment: What version of Chrome are you using?

Comment: I use chrome version 3.0.191.3 .Now my problem has been solved. I solved my problem in order to the following answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Historically `<a name="top"></a>` did not work in some browsers because there was nothing between the tags.  Maybe this is the problem?

Try wrapping the tags around the first thing to display on the page (e.g. your site logo, if you have it in the top left).

Answer (score 3):

You can use an ID instead for anchor links - this is the preferred method nowadays because it saves adding in `<a>` tags when unnecessary. For a "back to top" link, add an ID to the `<body>` tag:

```
<body id="top">
...
<a href="#top">back to top</a>
</body>
```